# How to solve many Differential equations and Plot?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, function-construction, parametric-functions

```
    w1 = 1;
    w2 = 1;
    g1 = 1;
    sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x1'[t] - y1[t]*w1 - z1[t]*g1 -w2*x2[t] == 
    0, x2'[t] - x1[t]*w2 - z2[t]*g2 - y1[t]*w2 == 0, 
    y1'[t] - x2[t]*w1 - x1[t]*g1 - z1[t]*w1 - y2[t]*g2 == 0, 
    y2'[t] - y1[t]*g1 - x2[t]*w1 - z2[t]*w1 == 0, 
    z1'[t] - y2[t]*g2 - z2[t]*w2 == 0, 
    z2'[t] - z1[t]*w1 - y1[t]*g2 == 0, x1[0] == 0, x2[0] == 0, 
    y1[0] = 0, y2[0] == 0, z1[0] == 1, z2[0] == 1}, {x1, x2, y1, y2, 
    z1, z2}, {g2, 0, 1}, t];
    Manipulate[
    ParametricPlot[{(sol[g2][[5]][t] + sol[g2][[6]][t])/2, g2}, {g2, 0, 
        1}, AspectRatio -> 1, AxesLabel -> {(Q), (g2)}], {{t, 50}, 0, 1, 
    Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

I want to plot the graph between mean value of (z1+z2)/2 and g2. How it is possible if i have differential equation with respect to time? Here i have tried to solve with parametric function but it is showing error. Should i vary time? Anyhow i want to plot. We can vary time upto any desired value. I need plot. If anyone can solve this most welcome..

Answer (score 0):

First, I correct some typos in your code, this should give solution without errors:

```
w1 = 1;
w2 = 1;
g1 = 1;
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x1'[t] - y1[t]*w1 - z1[t]*g1 - 
 w2*x2[t] == 0, x2'[t] - x1[t]*w2 - z2[t]*g2 - y1[t]*w2 == 0, 
 y1'[t] - x2[t]*w1 - x1[t]*g1 - z1[t]*w1 - y2[t]*g2 == 0, 
 y2'[t] - y1[t]*g1 - x2[t]*w1 - z2[t]*w1 == 0, 
 z1'[t] - y2[t]*g2 - z2[t]*w2 == 0, 
 z2'[t] - z1[t]*w1 - y1[t]*g2 == 0, x1[0] == 0, x2[0] == 0, 
 y1[0] == 0, y2[0] == 0, z1[0] == 1, z2[0] == 1}, {x1, x2, y1, y2, 
 z1, z2}, {t, 0, 50}, g2]
```

If I understood your code, `g2` is a parameter and `t` goes from 0 to 50, but you can correct values.

Now define two helper functions:

```
zz1[g2_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := sol[g2][[5]][t]
zz2[g2_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := sol[g2][[6]][t]
```

and we can make various plots. I chose `LogPlot` because functions grow very rapidly.

```
Manipulate[LogPlot[(zz1[g2, t] + zz2[g2, t])/2, {g2, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {HoldForm[g2],
  Row[{"(", HoldForm[z1 + z2], ")", "\[ThinSpace]/\[ThinSpace]", 2}]}],
{t, 0, 50, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Or you can plot in 3D:

```
Plot3D[(zz1[g2, t] + zz2[g2, t])/2, {g2, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 10}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> "Log", PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {HoldForm[g2], HoldForm[t], HoldForm[(z1 + z2)/2]}]
```

[image]